# Why isn't this capturing the [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I have a piece of code like

```
foreach(var controller in controllers)
{
   // ... 
   var actions = controller.GetMethods()
                           .Where(method => method.ReturnType == typeof(IHttpActionResult));
   foreach(var action in actions)
   {
      // ... 
      var httpMethodAttribute = action.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault() as System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorAttribute;
      // ... 
   }
}
```

but for some reason `httpMethodAttribute` is always `null` even  when I can confirm that the `action` has a `CustomAttribute` that `is` a `System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If my answer was satisfactory, would you mind accepting it?  If not, let me know and I'll expand on it.

Answer (score 3):

`GetCustomAttributes(..., true)` only gets attributes of the exact type you specify, searching up the inheritance hierarchy of the member you're calling `GetCustomAttributes` on.  It doesn't get attributes that inherit from the attribute type you're searching for.

To get a `HttpGetAttribute`, you'll need to call `GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HttpGetAttribute), true)`.  Same thing with the `HttpPostAttribute`.

For example, if you have an action method `Foo` that overrides a method from a parent controller, and the parent's `Foo` had an attribute, the second parameter would tell `GetCustomAttributes` whether to return the parents custom attribute.

Answer (score 1):

a year too late, but if you wish to get the HttpMethodAttribute:

```
var httpMethodAttr = (HttpMethodAttribute)action.GetCustomAttributes()
                        .SingleOrDefault(a => typeof(HttpMethodAttribute).IsAssignableFrom(a.GetType());
```

or if the type is what you are after

```
var httpMethodType = (from a in action.GetCustomAttributes()
                      let t = a.GetType()
                      where typeof(HttpMethodAttribute).IsAssignableFrom(t)
                      select t).SingleOrDefault();
if (httpMethodType = null || httpMethodType == typeof(HttpGetAttribute))
```